# Infix to postfix by stack

Tags: algorithms

Convert in postfix

(((P+Q)*(R+S))/T) +(A*(B+C)) 
note : there is *  between (P+Q) (R+s)
My attempt in image  [image: POSTFIX] and size of stack = 15 given, but iam getting size =13

Comment: What do you expect? I do not see any question here.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: Infix and postfix describe the same tree, one in pre- and the other in post-order.

Comment: @ Evil  read last line its not my fault that you dont see any question   and size of stack = 15 given, but iam getting size =13

Comment: @ Raphael what have you tried seriously ??? that image is drawn by me only after solving it it on paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which way you are following to solve the problem. After seeing your problem I tried on the paper with the same above equation, got the correct postfix expression.

You can follow this link for understanding and be solving the infix to postfix expression https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXPL6UavUeA

Comment: We prefer the answer to be self-contained, with textual description, not only link to some resource. I do not fully understand the question (there is the statement about stack size only), so it would be good idea to wait until OP clarifies the question before making an answer. If you have already tried to solve it on paper, maybe you could write it here? The answer would be far better then.

Comment: @Sanjay Nag  my postfix expression is correct iam sure , so why you said you got correct postfix expression

Comment: @sumitgoyal I didn't understand what you are actually looking for. Please specify your question clearly as Evil Said in above comments. If you are talking about the stack space, when you are pushing the symbols and poping the symbols will be done by one stack. If my explanation is not clear, you can find the above link to my post. It may help you in finding the solution.